# | discord.py | I am making a 24/7 chanting bot for my server but I get this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ss' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am a beginner at discord.py and can't understand why my bot is not correctly. I use VS Code IDE to code and execute my bot through the Command Prompt or Repl.it. I am making a bot to chant some lines 24/7 in my discord server.

When I try to run my bot and write "ch!start" in my server, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\bot.py", line 36, in on_message
    await chant()
  File "...\bot.py", line 17, in chant
    if ss == 'not chanting':
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ss' referenced before assignment
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Here is my code:

```py
# bot.py
#disabled from keep_alive import keep_alive
import discord
import os
import time

client = discord.Client()

ss = 'not chanting'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
  print('I am ready to chant.')

async def chant():
  if ss == 'not chanting':
    ss = chanting
    print('changed not chanting to chanting')
  
  elif ss == 'chanting':
    ss = 'not chanting'
    print('changed chanting to not chanting')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    sendmsg = message.channel.send
    author = message.author

    if msg == 'ch!help':
      await sendmsg('**24/7 Chanter**\nch!help - gives a list of commands I can do\nch!start - starts chanting in the specified channel\nch!stop - stops chanting')
    
    if msg == 'ch!start':
      if ss == 'not chanting':
        await chant()
        await sendmsg('Ok. Chanting now.')
        await sendmsg('(This message triggers the code to chant.) reference')
      
      elif ss == 'chanting':
        await sendmsg('I **am** chanting!')

    if msg == 'ch!stop':
      if ss == 'chanting':
        await chant()
        await sendmsg('Ok. Stopping chanting...')
        await sendmsg('Please wait...')

      elif ss == 'not chanting':
        await sendmsg('I **am not** chanting!')

    if msg.endswith('reference'):
      await sendmsg('passed test 1')
      if author == client.user:
        await sendmsg('passed test 2')
        if ss == 'chanting':
          await sendmsg('passed test 3')
          await asyncio.time(4)
          await sendmsg('passed test 4')
          await sendmsg('(MSG)')
          await asyncio.time(1)
          await sendmsg('(MSG)')
          await asyncio.time(3)
          await sendmsg('(MSG)')
          await asyncio.time(7)
          await sendmsg('(MSG)')
          await asyncio.time(9)
          await sendmsg('(MSG)')
          await asyncio.time(5)
          await sendmsg('(MSG) reference')
    
client.run('no token 4 u')
```

Comment: Because in the method you are assigning value to variable ss, ss comes into local scope. Global ss is not considered now. And since you are comparing ss with some value, but it is not assigned in the method, you're getting the error

Comment: In short, use global ss, to use global variable. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: also, `ss = chanting` will raise an error, because chanting is not a variable, should be `ss = 'chanting'`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors. One is in `async def chanting():` Try `ss = 'chanting'`, not `ss = chanting`. Also, ss is not a global variable. You need to make it one. View comments for how to do that.